# Are there general rules for Base + Metal Compound reactions like there are for Acids?

Tags: acid-base, metal

Are there general rules for Base + Metal Compound reactions like there are for Acids?

For example, acids have some general rules.

**

Acid + Metal => Salt + Hydrogen Gas

Acid + Metal Carbonate => Salt + Water + Carbon Dioxide

Acid + Metal Oxide => Salt + Water

Acid + Metal Hydroxide => Salt + Water

**

Are there equivalent rules for bases?

Base + Metal => ?

Answer (score 1):

On the same level of generalization, the rule is "no reaction", but this rule has quite a few exceptions (probably more than the rules you quoted above).

Water-soluble bases would react with [amphoteric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphoterism) metals to produce hydrogen and the corresponding salt:
$$2\ce{Al + 2KOH + 6H2O \to 2KAl(OH)4 + 3H2}$$

Comment: How can a metal be 'amphoteric'? Metals undergo redox reaction instead of acid-base reactions, don't they?

Comment: Just like that.

Comment: So if I write in an examination that certain metal is amphoteric, will it be accepted by a general examiner? Or calling a metal amphoteric is something done in informal talk and should be avoided in the exams?

Comment: @Aumkaar I think it will be accepted.